# Google doc viewer iframe with docs inside a protected area

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, iframe

I am embedding files display in my page using google doc viewer :

```
$('#previewContainer').html('<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://www.example.com/'+file+'&#038;embedded=true" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none;"></iframe>') ;
```

The files are inside a folder which cannot be accessed from outside. I have blocked access with a htaccess coded this way :

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

In order to have the viewer work, I have added this line to the htaccess:

```
allow from google.com
```

Now I'm trying to think on a security point of view. Is it possible for someone to make the htaccess think the request comes from 127.0.0.1 or from google.com, and therefore get access to the files ?
If yes, how can I prevent that ?